# OpenXML CellValue is giving Hexadecimal Value While Reading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, openxml

```html
foreach (Row row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                                        {
                                            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
                                            if (!firstRow)
                                            {
                                                int count = row.Elements<Cell>().Count();
                                                //await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Cell Count:  [{count}]");
                                                var firstCol = true;
                                                foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                                                {
                                                    if (!firstCol)
                                                    {
                                                        int id = -1;
                                                        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                                                        {
                                                            if (int.TryParse(cell.InnerText, out id))
                                                            {
                                                                var value = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(id).InnerText;
                                                                data.Add(value);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else if (cell.DataType == null && cell.CellValue != null)
                                                        {
                                                            data.Add(cell.CellValue.Text.ToString());
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            data.Add(string.Empty);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        firstCol = false;
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                rowList.Add(data);
                                            }
                                            else 
                                            {
                                                firstRow = false;
                                            }

                                        }
```

When CellValue is not null the value come is the shape of Hexadecimal format which is saved as string in the ArrayList. I want the Actual Value which is saved in the Excel sheet.

Comment: Instead of reading the raw data use a library like ExcelReader or Epplus

Comment: What *is* the original value? And what does `hexadecimal format` mean? If the cell contained a string `Text` would return it. `ToString()` isn't needed because `Text` is already a string.

Comment: This is the actual value in cell 0.01887 and in cellvalue is showing 1.8870000000000001E-2

Comment: That's the same number in scientific notation. Not hex -that would be something like `0x402C9CDA2D0`. How numbers appear in Excel depends on the cell's style. `Text` is the display text, not the actual stored value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cell.InnerText here

```
if (int.TryParse(cell.InnerText, out id))
```

you should use cell.CellValue.Text so change that row to

```
if (int.TryParse(cell.CellValue.Text, out id))
```

I used to do the following when reading a string text from a cell

```
private static string ReadCell(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorkbookPart workbookPart)
{
  var cellValue = cell.CellValue;
  var text = (cellValue == null) ? cell.InnerText : cellValue.Text;
  if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
  {
    text = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable
      .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(cell.CellValue.Text)).InnerText;
  }
  return (text ?? string.Empty).Trim();
}
```